# Flyback Synchronous rectification voltage-second balance control

Tags: analog, switch-mode-power-supply, control, flyback

Below figure is a flyback with Synchronous rectification.

there is a control method call voltage-second balance to use to control the Q2 switch.

I see this picture from internet, but I can't find it again, so I draw it by myself.

and there are some questions I would like to ask.

1.I would like to find some IC which has this function to control the Q2, can anyone suggest me?

2.I would like to use simluation tool like PSIM or SIMPLIS to simulate it, but I don't know how to use analog device to model the S/H and ZVD (zero voltage detect), could you please give me some advice on that.

[image]

Comment: S/H means sample and hold.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I know that, I just curious about how to use analog circuit to built